# geometry sets footskip too small

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I'm using the `geometry` package to change the header and footer of my page to specific values. Until now, it wasn't possible for me to get the footer in the right dimensions. The header looks has its 17mm, but the footer doesn't. Here is a minimal example which I compile with `LuaLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[paper = a4]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{blindtext, fontspec}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainheadsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[  includeheadfoot
            , headheight = 17mm
            , footskip = 17mm
            , tmargin = 0mm
            , bmargin = 0mm
            , verbose
           ]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Do you have an idea, how to get a footer with 17 mm, too?

Comment: I guess that `footskip` is not the footer size. I guess that it is the space between the text and the footer.

Comment: `geometry` dutifully does what you ask it to: the baseline of the footer is just on the bottom margin of the paper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want that the distance of the footline separator from the bottom is 17mm. Thus you have to do the computation in a different way:

```
\documentclass[paper = a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext,fontspec}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline,
  plainheadsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\normalfont\normalsize
\usepackage[
  includehead,
  headheight = 17mm,
  footskip = \dimexpr\headsep+\ht\strutbox\relax,
  tmargin = 0mm,
  bmargin = \dimexpr17mm+2\ht\strutbox\relax,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, why is it so easy for the head and much more complex for the footer?

Comment: @Dirk LaTeX outputs a top margin, the header in a box of the required height, the header separation, the type block and finally leaves the `\footskip` space and typesets the footer line. There is no "footer box" of a predetermined height. `geometry` uses the `bmargin` specification to compute the type block size.